Haar measure on circle group as closed subgroup of the complex general linear group

The circle group $\operatorname{U}(1)$ is a Lie subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^\times = \operatorname{GL}(1,\mathbb{C})$.
It inherits a Haar measure via the identification $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.
For the Lie group $\operatorname{GL}(1,\mathbb{C})$, $\frac{1}{|z|^2}dz=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}dxdy$ is a Haar measure, where we set $z= x+iy$.

How are these two Haar measures related, and how does one in general recover a Haar measure on a closed (and not open) subgroup?
The following question is related, but I would like to see a more explicit construction or a more precise reference.
